# OpenLayers: simple example heatmap

Tags: openlayers, heatmap

I would like to display an heatmap on a map generated with OpenLayer.
I tried two different ways to get the heatmap, the first one.

```
<html><body>
<div id="demoMap"></div>
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script>
map = new OpenLayers.Map("demoMap");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
map.zoomToMaxExtent();
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
heatmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Heatmap("Heatmap Layer", map, layer, null,
 {visible: true, radius: 15},
 {isBaseLayer: false, opacity: 0.3, projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")});
var lon, lat, c;
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
 lon = i;
 lat = i;
 c = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
 heatmap.addDataPoint(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), c);
}

</script>
</body></html>
```

the second one

```
<html><body>
 <div id="demoMap"></div>
 <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
 <script>
 var testData={
 max: 46,
 data: [{lat: 33.5363, lon:-117.044, count: 1}, {lat: 35.8278, lon:-78.6421, count: 1}]
 };
 layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer( "OpenLayers WMS",
 "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'}
 );
 map = new OpenLayers.Map("demoMap");
 map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
 map.zoomToMaxExtent();
 heatmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Heatmap( "Heatmap Layer", map, layer,
 {visible: true, radius:10}, {isBaseLayer: false, opacity: 0.3}
 );
 heatmap.setDataSet(testData);
 map.addLayer(heatmap);
  </script>
</body></html>
```

I can only visualize the map without the heatmap layer. 
Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem, as you should be able to see in the Javascript console, is that OpenLayers.Layer.Heatmap does not exist. There are no references to it at all in the [github repo](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers.git) either.

You can confirm this by running:

```
git clone https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers.git
grep -ri HeatMap openlayers/lib/OpenLayers
```

There is a great [heatmap example](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/heatMap.html) but note this is in the camptocamp sandbox and requires a custom build and the inclusion of a couple of extra classes, which can be seen here: http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector/ one of which is the `OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.Heatmap` class.

In OpenLayer3, heatmaps are part of the trunk, see [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/heatmap-earthquakes.html?q=heatmap).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 libraries for Openlayers heatmap, additional to mentioned in the previous answer:

**1) Solution 1 :**

Javascript code & example is located in below URL:
https://github.com/hoehrmann/openlayers-heatmap

*Snippet of code:*

```
var heat = new Heatmap.Layer("Heatmap");
heat.addSource(new Heatmap.Source(new OpenLayers.LonLat(9.434, 54.740)));
heat.addSource(new Heatmap.Source(new OpenLayers.LonLat(9.833, 54.219)));
...
map.addLayer(heat);
map.zoomToExtent(heat.getDataExtent());
```

**2) Solution 2**
Below library contains heatmap for Openlayers,Arcgis, googlemaps, leaflet
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Javascript_Free_Code/Canvas_Library/Download_heatmap_js_Free_Java_Code.htm